# How to obtain file_id from "file name" in Box.com API

Tags: box-api, box

I am looking to use the Box.com API to download a file. Their API documentation shows that a `file_id` is required to call the API endpoint. However, I cannot find how to obtain the `file_id`. How do you obtain the `file_id` if all you have is the file name?

Along the same lines what if the file is located in a specific directory within the Box.com user's account. Can you obtain the `file_id` from a given path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a Box file id by searching for the file by name using the [Box API Search endpoint](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#searching-for-content).

Comment: The Search endpoint isn't quite reliable. If I upload a file with a certain name into a folder, and then search for it filtering by parentID, the search service doesn't find it. I guess there must be some kind of search index update delay after a new file is uploaded.

Comment: @fede, we've seen that as well.  There is a delay between creating a file and being able to search for the file.  There are a couple workarounds we've found.  You can iterate across folder items looking for items with a name, which works but is slow.  If you have write access to the folder, you can do a preflight check for uploading a named file to a folder.  If a file with that name exists within the folder, the preflight check will fail with a conflict exception, which contains the id of the existing file.  This prevents having to do folder item iteration.